# Не определяется $_COOKIE через ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, cookie, php

В файле  script.js. Первая часть устанавливает куки

```
// установка куки
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "name.php"
});
```

Содержимое файла name.php

```
setcookie('cookie', 'cookie', time()+(60*60*24),  '/');
```

Вторая часть файла  script.js должна читать и выводить в на экран

```
 $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "file/cooc.php"
     })
     .done(function(msg) {
         $('#fn').html(msg);
     });
 });
```

Содержимое файла cooc.php

```
$newname = $_COOKIE['cookie'];
echo $newname;
```

В браузере сама кука появляется, но через фаил name.php не определяется. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: `setcookie()` не обновляет автоматически массив `$_COOKIE`, если вы про это.

Comment: Не совсем понял? Допустим, но при обновлении стреицы кука остается, но ее по прежнему не прочитать из файла cooc.php.  Я пробовал даже в самом файле ее устанавливать и тут же читать, но результата нет

Answer (score 3):

Добавьте в конструкцию ajax **headers: {'Cookie' : document.cookie }**, тогда куки будут передаваться в заголовке и вы сможете из вызвать в cooc.php.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "file/cooc.php",
        headers: {
            'Cookie': document.cookie
        }

    })
    .done(function(msg) {
        $('#fn').html(msg);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте плагин jquery.cookie для динамической работы с Cookie (без перезагрузки страницы).

[Ссылка на Git](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Пример: `$.cookie('name', 'value');`